# Raster effect on (background)images for website

Tags: html, css

I want to create something like this as a background for websites:

[image]

What is the best method for achieving this raster-like effect?

Comment: Try a black background, two radial gradients, and two repeating linear gradients. You might be able to draw inspiration from [Lea Verou’s CSS3 gallery](http://lea.verou.me/css3patterns/) on that last part.

Comment: Ok, but i want to have an image an the raster is on top of the image.

Comment: So use two repeating linear gradients.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Julian

Use the CSS `z-index` property to layer and style the `html` element with the CSS3 gradient background and layer and style the `body` element with the raster background.

**Note:** *You can use CSS gradient backgrounds or an actual image for the background. Remember to implement fallbacks to support older browsers that do not support CSS3 gradient backgrounds and Data URIs.*

**Check out the code and demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/QMtK9/

```
<style>
*{margin:0;padding:0;border:0}
html{
background:#eee;/*Old browsers*/
background:#eee -moz-linear-gradient(top,rgba(255,255,255,.2) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,.2) 100%);/*FF3.6+*/
background:#eee -webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,color-stop(0%,rgba(255,255,255,.2)),color-stop(100%,rgba(0,0,0,.2)));/*Chrome,Safari4+*/
background:#eee -webkit-linear-gradient(top,rgba(255,255,255,.2) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,.2) 100%);/*Chrome10+,Safari5.1+*/
background:#eee -o-linear-gradient(top,rgba(255,255,255,.2) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,.2) 100%);/*Opera11.10+*/
background:#eee -ms-linear-gradient(top,rgba(255,255,255,.2) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,.2) 100%);/*IE10+*/
background:#eee linear-gradient(top,rgba(255,255,255,.2) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,.2) 100%);/*W3C*/
z-index:1 !important
}
html,body{height:100%;min-height:100%;background-attachment:fixed}
html body{position:relative !important}
body{
background:transparent url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAQAAAAECAYAAACp8Z5+AAAAEklEQVQImWNgYGD4z0AswK4SAFXuAf8EPy+xAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC) repeat center center !important;
z-index:2 !important
}
</style>
```

Additional Resources:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Understanding_z_index
- https://www.google.com/#q=css+z-index

Answer (score 0):

2 seconds of googling gave my this website: http://www.patternify.com/

Answer (score 0):

This is what I do by myself:

1. I create a square in photoshop (this can be 3x3 or 5x5 or whatever)
2. Make one part black, and the other part transparant or half-transparant
3. Save them as png

And then I will need a second image which will be used for colors

1. Create some colors in photoshop
2. Make image half transparant
3. Save it as .png

Then in CSS3 I would place it like this:

```
body {
   background-image: url("images/raster.png");
   background-repeat: repeat;
}
#wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: url("images/colorimage.png") top center no-repeat;
}
```